# Error in DGL API with heterogeneous graphs

Tags: python, algorithm, pytorch, graphml, dgl

According to this page (https://docs.dgl.ai/en/0.9.x/generated/dgl.DGLGraph.nodes.html)

This code snippet

```
g = dgl.graph((torch.tensor([0, 1]), torch.tensor([1, 2])))
hg = dgl.heterograph({
    ('user', 'follows', 'user'): (torch.tensor([0, 1]), torch.tensor([1, 2])),
    ('user', 'plays', 'game'): (torch.tensor([3, 4]), torch.tensor([5, 6]))
})
```

indicates that there are 5 nodes of type user which are 0,1,2,3,4 and 2 nodes of type game which are 5 and 6. However, when I print `hg.nodes('game')` I get

`tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`

Am I missing something or is there a big error with the DGL API?